# Sorting a list of lists in an specific order

Tags: java, sorting, collections, rx-java, guava

This question is about sorting lists.

I have a generic method to get Vehicles

```
List<Vehicle>  getRandomVehiclesList() {    
   return  fetchVehicles(); 
   //returns List <Car>, List<Bus>, etc
   };
```

Vehicles can be Car, Motorcycle, Bus, Truck, SUV, etc.

```
Car extends Vehicle
Bus extends Vehicle
```

Say I want to call 5 times  getRandomVehiclesList() and then sort the resulted 5 lists in an specific order.

—————————————————————————————————

THE LIST NEEDS TO BE IN THIS ORDER

```
List<Car>
List<Truck>
List<SUV>
List<Bus>
List<Motorcycle>
```

—————————————————————————————————

but the results can be returned in this order or other random order.

```
List<Bus>
List<Motorcycle>
List<Truck>
List<Car>
List<SUV>
```

What is the best way to sort all the lists so they match the order shown above (Car,Truck,Suv,Bus,Motorcycle)

Can RxJava be used to simplify?

Comment: There is no difference between `List<Car>` and `List<Truck>` at runtime - they're both just `List`s. The only way you can do this is to pick an element from the list to determine the probable type, and sort on that basis. Of course, that's tricky if your list is empty, or if you've got a `List<Vehicle>`, since that could contain both a `Car` and a `Truck`.

Comment: how can you guaaranty that calling the method ***getRandomVehiclesList*** will return only Cars or Trucks??, they are all the same interface Vehicle

Comment: It is guaranteed to return only Cars or Trucks.   I was thinking maybe adding them into a list of lists like a Multimap , and sort with a new comparator that will tell you the order based on an index. What do you think?

Comment: Andy Turner is spot on. If you need to handle potential empty lists, then you need to return something other than a List. An object containing the list, and the type of vehicles in the list, for example. An enum would be a good choice to represent the type of a vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create your own `Comparator<List<Vehicle>>` taking advantage of Guava's `Ordering.explicit` comparator:

```
class VehicleListComparator implements Comparator<List<Vehicle>> {
    private final Ordering<Class<? extends Vehicle>> vehicleClassOrdering;

    public VehicleListComparator(Ordering<Class<? extends Vehicle>> vehicleClassOrdering) {
        this.vehicleClassOrdering = vehicleClassOrdering;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(List<Vehicle> vehiclesList1, List<Vehicle> vehiclesList2) {
        Class<? extends Vehicle> left = getVehicleClass(vehiclesList1);
        Class<? extends Vehicle> right = getVehicleClass(vehiclesList2);
        return vehicleClassOrdering.compare(left, right);
    }

    private Class<? extends Vehicle> getVehicleClass(List<Vehicle> vehicleList) {
        if (vehicleList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            return vehicleList.get(0).getClass();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then sort your list of vehicle lists using this comparator:

```
Ordering<Class<? extends Vehicle>> vehicleClassOrdering = Ordering.explicit(Arrays.asList(
        Car.class, Truck.class, SUV.class, Bus.class, Motorcycle.class));
Collections.sort(vehicleLists, new VehicleListComparator(vehicleClassOrdering));
```